# PSR for using description of class

Tags: php, phpdoc, psr-2, psr-1

I can't find anything saying in PSR about where should placed comment about class and namespace. Is it should be first description of class or namespace?

```
<?php
/**
 * Some description about this class
 *
 * @author      Mr. Anderson
 * @since       06/09/17
 * @package
 *
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass
{
}
```

Or properly that?

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

/**
 * Some description about this class
 *
 * @author      Mr. Anderson
 * @since       06/09/17
 * @package
 *
 */

class MyClass
{
}
```

Comment: PSR doesn't cover [phpdoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/). I'd put them right before the `class` keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PSR` has nothing to do with this. `PSR` says nothing about docblocks.

What really matters is the way that your comments are treated by `phpdoc`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Some description about this class
 *
 * @author      Mr. Anderson
 * @since       06/09/17
 * @package
 *
 */

namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass
{
}
```

is treated like you have a comment for a **file**, but don't have a comment for an exact class `MyClass`, so after generating documentation there will be an error that you don't have a class description.

In second case:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

/**
 * Some description about this class
 *
 * @author      Mr. Anderson
 * @since       06/09/17
 * @package
 *
 */

class MyClass
{
}
```

`phpdoc` will consider docblock as comment to a **class** `Myclass`, but will not find comment to a full file. So you will still have an error after generating docs.

But, with both of this approaches I would select second, because it is better to have **class** description, then file description.

Comment: As hinted by @u_mulder, phpDocumentor expects to see *both* the file-level docblock (his first example) *and* the class-level docblock (his second example)... so I suggest using both.  If you want to specifically document the namespace itself, that docblock should come after the file-level docblock, before the namespace line itself.